# Multiple route aliases in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a Rails 4 application with some routes:

```
resources :users
resources :notifications
resources :comments
...
```

My client asked me to have urls in english and spanish. I've been googling and found that I could use *path* attribute like this:

```
resources :users, path: 'usuarios'
resources :notifications, path: 'notificaciones'
resources :comments, path: 'comentarios'
```

This enables me to access */usuarios, /notificaciones, /comentarios* but when I go to /users I receive *No route matches [GET] "/users"*, and I need both routes.

I tried the following:

```
['users', 'usuarios'].each do |p|
    resources :users, path: p
end
['notifications', 'notificaciones'].each do |p|
    resources :notifications, path: p
end
['comments', 'comentarios'].each do |p|
    resources :comments, path: p
end
```

This worked well, but is there a simpler way to do this? Something like:

```
resources :users, path: ['users', 'usuarios']
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclamer: an old question, but because it's the first result in Google, I'm answering it now.*

You cas use **translated paths** like this:

```rb
scope(path_names: { new: 'neu', edit: 'bearbeiten' }) do
  resources :categories, path: 'kategorien'
end
```

Source : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths